# Python and OpenCV - How do we define region?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I came across the following code:

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('xyz.jpg')
(h, w) = image.shape[:2]
# compute the center of the image
(cX, cY) = (w / 2, h / 2)
region = image[0:cY, 0:cX]
```

How can we read this part `image[0:cY, 0:cX]`? I tried printing out the result, but got an array printed out that couldn't help me understand the idea.

So, for instance, let's say that the center of the image was `(50,50)`, how would `region` be defined in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't that just meant to crop half of the image? Top half of the image?